# how to get year and month into number oracle

Tags: oracle

i'm trying to get sysdate year and month into number or char.

I'd want something like this:

`202107`

or last month

`202106`

i tried this code:

`select trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM') from dual;`

please help, thanks

Comment: Incidentally, if youre doing this to store a date into an int column, please for the love of a relevant deity, don't. Change the column to datetime and store TRUNC(somedate, 'MM') in it instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to a string and then to a number:

```sql
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1), 'YYYYMM'))
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or, you can use extract and wrap it in a sub-query so you do not need to repeat adding the months:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt) * 100 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt)
FROM   (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1) AS dt
  FROM   DUAL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year from sysdate) * 100 + EXTRACT(month from sysdate)
```

If you want to scroll around, manipulate the date *before* you extract from it, rather than minusing after you extract (gets tricky to e.g. go back a month if the date is in jan)

```
--will work for jan 2021
SELECT EXTRACT(year from ADD_MONTHS(somedate, -1)) * 100 + EXTRACT(month from ADD_MONTHS(somedate, -1))

--won't work for jan 2021
SELECT EXTRACT(year from somedate) * 100 + (EXTRACT(month from somedate) - 1)
```

TRUNC is a device that "rounds" a date to a particular interval, such as "trimming the time off a datetime" or "making any day of the week back to the date that was the start of the week" - very useful for all sorts of stuff like "total sales by month - `SUM(sale) GROUP BY TRUNC(saledate, 'mm')`" but it keeps all the components of the date (the day, the hour, the minute etc) so it isn't what you want.